# Errorbar in ggplot is using SD or SE as default

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I use `stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=.3)` to add an errorbar to my plot. But I do not know the errorbar means standard deviation (SD) or standard error (SE). I wanna make sure my description is right. Do any guys know this and please give a help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [instructions](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#Helper%20functions):

> First, it is necessary to summarize the data. This can be done in a
>   number of ways, as described on this page. In this case, we’ll use the
>   `summarySE()` function defined on that page, and also at the bottom of
>   this page. (The code for the `summarySE` function must be entered before
>   it is called here).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, AK88's answer is correct and captures the key point. However, I always found the reference to the r-cookbook and its `summarySE()` approach a little indirect and potentially confusing. I would offer the following approach based on pipes exemplified using mtcars:

```
require(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
summarise(mpgSD = sd(mpg),
        mpg = mean(mpg),
        lower = mpg - mpgSD,
        upper = mpg + mpgSD) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=1, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper)) + ylim(0,30)
```

Using dplyr's summarise you can easily define your lower and upper values and those are referenced in `geom_errorbar` / `geom_linerange` ...

Comment: Very Simple and efficient.